# Recovering source code of uncommited new file after running unit test in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

In Xcode, I added a new file with unit tests. I somehow did not commit the file and now the file is empty. I did run the unit tests a few times and was wondering if could recover the Swift source file from Xcode (e.g. temp files?)

Comment: Unfortunately, if you did not commit the file (or stash it), then git has no way of recovering it if the file or its contents got deleted somehow

Comment: I understand. I was wondering about xCode temp files.

Answer (score 0):

Since Git is not involved (the file was not added to the index or committed), check if [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/back-up-files-mh35860/mac) has a backup of your file.

IF [Time Machine was enabled](https://www.imore.com/how-set-and-start-using-time-machine), you might recover your file that way.